# Multiple timelines on one chart in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I’m looking to make the following chart in highcharts

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eh9QTsiENZkQoipKkoYglNN_IJFqlkez

What is the best way to do so?

- Should I be using use some variation of the timeline chart API (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/timeline), or
- Should I be using some variation of the scatter chart with horizontal lines? (https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/scatter-chart)

Any guidance and code samples would be much appreciated

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use a variation of the scatter chart with horizontal lines. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```js
function generateLineData(year) {
  return [
    [+new Date('01-01-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('04-01-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('07-01-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('10-01-2019'), year]
  ]
}

function generateScatterData(year) {
  return [
    [+new Date('01-10-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('01-27-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('03-08-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('04-13-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('04-13-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('07-22-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('08-03-2019'), year],
    [+new Date('09-23-2019'), year]
  ]
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      formatter: function() {
        const values = [2017, 2018, 2019]

        if (values.includes(this.value)) {
          return this.value;
        }

        return '';
      }
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
     formatter: function () {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.value);
      }
    }
  },
  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
     enableMouseTracking: false,
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      color: '#bbb',
      lineWidth: 3
    },
    scatter: {
      colorByPoint: true,
      marker: {
        symbol: 'circle',
        radius: 7,
        lineWidth: 2
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    id: 'main',
    name: 'line series',
    data: generateLineData(2017)
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    data: generateLineData(2018)
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    data: generateLineData(2019)
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: generateScatterData(2017)
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: generateScatterData(2018)
  }, {
    linkedTo: 'main',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: generateScatterData(2019)
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6Lq4b01k/